# Jenkins: how to save changelog for build

Tags: save, integration, jenkins, continuous, changelog

I have Jenkins-CI and C++ project under SVN.
How to save changelog between successfull builds into text (or html) file ?
Does Jenkins have any variable/temp file with content of .../changes page?

Answer (score 2):

Here is XPath code that can get you the changeset for a given build id via Jenkins API:

```
http://[jenkins_host]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=//build/id[text()='${BUILD_ID}']/../changeSet
```

(Put actual build id instead of ${BUILD_ID}). This can be used by a script (say, a Pyhon script utilizing [Python Jenkins](http://packages.python.org/python-jenkins/)) that collects changeset results in the end of every build and stores them in a temp locations. After a successful build the script can collect all results stored since the previous build and process them.