# How can I persist Jenkins status page?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, commit, jenkins-plugins, status

I would like to persist the status page of a Jenkins build job's build (the one which contains commits as well as why the build was triggered).

This should happen in order to get a changelog file.

How am I able to do this?

For being a bit more precise, I would like to persist the content which is shown from

```
<jenkins-build-server-address>/job/<job-identifier>/<build-number>/api/json?pretty=true
```

as a file. A separate buildstep inside the buildjob which takes care of this, would be perfect!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. As long as you don't delete a particular build it is available later. Even after you run another build.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this earlier StackOverflow question "[Jenkins: how to save changelog for build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078474/jenkins-how-to-save-changelog-for-build)" may have the answer.

Comment: I also found this. But unfortunately it does not mention how I can persist the content from within a build job (e.g. as a separate buildstep).

Comment: @makomweb: The build is available in the api as soon as it starts, so you can access it from within the job. Have you tried it?

Comment: @AndersLindahl It would be great if you can explain this a bit more in detail.

Comment: @makomweb You could probably do that with the [PostBuildScript Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) and a custom script. That's the best I can come up with. Good luck.